# ISAPI Rewrite Syntax Help?

Tags: isapi

I'm struggling to get some code working for an old ASP store site I manage - I have added the following which works perfectly well

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cat/[^?/]*_(\d+)\.htm /store/prodList.asp?idcategory=$1 [QSA]
```

Problem is if the category page has more than one page!  As it adds another couple of parameters to the querystring like so

```
/store/prodList.asp?idcategory=102&curPage=2&sortField=sortorder
```

I'm looking for an example of taking three more querystring parameters and appending it to the rewritten URL... Can anyone help please?

So for example, currently the following URL works fine

```
cat/productname_5.htm ... equates to ... /store/prodList.asp?idcategory=5
```

I need to do something like the following when I have more than one page?  but don't know the ISAPI syntax?

```
cat/productname_5_2_sortorder.htm ... would equate to ... /store/prodList.asp?idcategory=5&curPage=2&sortField=sortorder
```

I hope that makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking, set the [L] argument to make it stop matching on first match. ?

But [L] requires you to order them by most restrictive first, 4 args, then 3, 2 etc...

```
  ReWriteRule ^/store/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /store/prodList.asp\?idcategory=$1&curPage=$2 [L]

  ReWriteRule ^/store/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/{0,1}$ /store/prodList.asp\?idcategory=$1&curPage=$2&sortField=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying - I have amended my question slightly as I don't think I explained myself very well - Please let me know if you could help with it?

Comment: my examples are a different , but same concept applies. try it out using the [L] 's and in order of 5 query string parameters, 4, 3 etc,,,

Comment: Awesome got it working based on your example above... VERY appreciated